# MySQL Slow ORDER BY when done on JOIN value?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, optimization, sql-order-by

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    c.*,
    cv.views
FROM 
    content AS c
JOIN
    content_views AS cv ON cv.content = c.record_num
WHERE 
    c.enabled = 1
ORDER BY
    cv.views
```

Quite simple, but it's really slow... Is there a way to make it faster ?

This is my EXPLAIN:

```
id     select_type     table     type     possible_keys          key          key_len     ref          rows     Extra
1      SIMPLE          c         ref      enabled_2,enabled      enabled      4           const        23947    Using temporary; Using filesort
1      SIMPLE          cv        eq_ref   PRIMARY                PRIMARY      4           c.record_num 1
```

**EDIT 2016-02-24**

Please note that usually, I use a LIMIT so the number of records returned in the EXPLAIN isn't entirely accurate, however for the sake of simplicity and because the performance doesn't change with the LIMIT or without it, I have removed it.

As requested in the comments, this is the result of my SHOW CREATE TABLE. As you can see, one of my table is MyISAM while the other is InnoDB.

```
CREATE TABLE `content` (
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename_2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `filename_3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `orig_filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `trailer_filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `thumbnail` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `embed` text NOT NULL,
 `description` text NOT NULL,
 `paysite` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `model` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `scheduled_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
 `date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `encoded_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `rating` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `length` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `submitter` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `approved` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `hotlinked` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
 `plug_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `enabled` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `main_thumb` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
 `xml` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `photos` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `mobile` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `modeltmp` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `movie_width` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `movie_height` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `source_thumb_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `related` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
 `force_related` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `record_num` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `webvtt_src` text NOT NULL,
 `category_thumb` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `related_date` date NOT NULL,
 `publish_ready` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`record_num`),
 KEY `encoded_date` (`encoded_date`,`photos`,`enabled`),
 KEY `filename` (`filename`),
 KEY `scheduled_date` (`scheduled_date`),
 KEY `enabled_2` (`enabled`,`length`,`photos`),
 KEY `enabled` (`enabled`,`encoded_date`,`photos`),
 KEY `rating` (`rating`,`enabled`,`photos`),
 KEY `token` (`token`),
 KEY `submitter` (`submitter`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `keywords` (`keywords`,`title`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `description` (`description`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `keywords_2` (`keywords`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=124207 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `content_views` (
 `views` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `content` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`content`),
 KEY `views` (`views`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Nothing alarming in that explain, information on the tables?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: What are you going to do with 23,947 rows in the resultset?  Surely not throw them onto a web page?

Comment: Well for the purpose of simplicity I removed the LIMIT, but the performance was the same with and without it. I have posted the CREATE TABLE in my main post

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT c.*, cv.views
FROM content c JOIN
     content_views cv
     ON cv.content = c.record_num
WHERE c.enabled = 1
ORDER BY cv.views;
```

The best indexes are probably `content(enabled, record_num)` and `content_views(content, views)`.  I am guessing that the performance even with these indexes will be similar to what you have now.

Comment: `(content, views)` would work better if it were `content=const ORDER BY views`.  What he has does not have the `views` ordered in _one_ place.  However, it _is_ useful because of being "covering".  That is, it _won't_ prevent 'filesort', but it also won't need to touch the data.  On the other, other, hand, this is probably InnoDB with only 2 columns.  If so, then the `(content, views)` would be redundant with the table!

Comment: And `(enabled, record_num)` won't help because it will want to pick up all of `c.*` while it is there.  It is surprising that his index on a 'flag' was even used.

Comment: @RickJames . . . The composite index is so the engine that use the index for the join before fetching the rest of the columns from the data pages.

Comment: I think the Handler does that step.